# Proportions barplot for a certain average within a variable

Tags: r

Hi im trying to figure Using the simple graphing functions in R, how to make a bar chart displaying the proportion of a outcome of a variable (unsolved homicides by year) this can be thought of as the percentage of
unsolved homicides for any specific year by dividing the
number of **unsolved** homicides that year by the **total** number of homicides that
year. from each percent calculated I want to put them all into one big bar plot 
 I have done this so far:

```
#create a table with desired data (Total cases and year)
(TC<-table(dataset$Crime.Solved,dataset$Year))
```

> ```
>  **Year** 
>  1980  1981  1982  1983  1984  1985  1986  1987  1988  1989  1990  1991  
>        1992  1993  1994
>
>  **No** 
>   6104  5177  5252  4925  4573  4522  4975  5076  5171  5491  5985  7048  
>        7676  7654  7095
>
>  **Yes**
>  16371 15446 14720 14179 12915 13250 14380 13101 13042 13834 14642 14876 
>        15506 16050 15469
>
>   **Year** 
>   1995  1996  1997  1998  1999  2000  2001  2002  2003  2004  2005  2006  
>    2007  2008  2009
>
>   **No** 
>   6571  5681  5458  4542  4241  4289  4608  4821  5112  4917  5082  5191  
>   5371  4931  4532
>
>  **Yes**
>   13970 12727 11735 10949  9896  9831 10627 10917 10854 10827 11249 11550 
>   11392 10186 10856
>
>  **Year**
>  2010  2011  2012  2013  2014
>
>  **No**
>   4328  4236  4391  4321  4312
>
>  **Yes**
>  10406 10163 10340  9774  9689
> ```

```
#create a table with desired data (unsolved cases and year)
(USC<-table(unsolvedCASES$Crime.Solved =="No",unsolvedCASES$Year))
```

> ```
> **Year**
> 1980 1981 1982 1983 1984 1985 1986 1987 1988 1989 1990 1991 1992 1993 
>        1994 1995 1996 1997
>
>   **TRUE**
>   6104 5177 5252 4925 4573 4522 4975 5076 5171 5491 5985 7048 7676 7654 
>        7095 6571 5681 5458
>
>   **Year**
>   1998 1999 2000 2001 2002 2003 2004 2005 2006 2007 2008 2009 2010 2011 
>        2012 2013 2014
>
>   **TRUE**
>   4542 4241 4289 4608 4821 5112 4917 5082 5191 5371 4931 4532 4328 4236 
>        4391 4321 4312
> ```

```
#now try to get the percent of unsolved homicides each year by deviding unsolved homicides each year by total homicides each year

proportions <- table((dataset$Crime.Solved=="No"/dataset$Crime.Solved ),dataset$Year)
```

however this just gives me errors saying that

> ("No", dataset$Crime.Solved) : ‘/’ not meaningful for factors

HELLPP!!

thanks !!

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ED9l.png][1]

Comment: Take a look at `?prop.table` . Once you make your original `hrobs` table, you can wrap it like `prop.table(hrobs, 1)` where the `1` will give you row percentages and if you change it to `2` you get column percentages. Then you can wrap the whole thing in `barplot(prop.table(hrobs, 1), beside=TRUE)` to hopefully get something close to what you want. If you could provide some example data and expected output it would be easier to give more detailed advice though.

Comment: @thelatemail i have edited the question to make my question more clear. hope you are still online to help !

Answer (score 1):

(This is an edit to my previous answer)
Here's a simple solution:
Let's assume your data looks roughly like this (with just the two variables included that are of interest to you):

```
df <- data.frame(
  Year = c(rep(1980,4), rep(1981,5), rep(1982,6)),
  Crime.Solved = c("yes","no","yes","yes","no","yes","no","no","yes","yes","no","no","yes","no","no"    )
)
```

Now you make a 2x2 frequency list:

```
freq <- table(df$Year, df$Crime.Solved)
```

Next you calculate the proportions row-wise (cf. the number 1):

```
data <- prop.table(freq, 1) 
              no       yes
  1980 0.2500000 0.7500000
  1981 0.6000000 0.4000000
  1982 0.6666667 0.3333333
```

The data of central interest to you--the proportions of unsolved crime per year-- are in the left-most column, that is, in `data[,1]`; to print the respective years under each bar, you access them via `rownames(data)`:

```
barplot(data[,1], main = "Proportions of unsolved crime per year",
    names.arg = row.names(data), las = 3)
```

[image]

Comment: Did this post answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very simple solution:

First, structure your data like this (with each variable in a separate column):

```
df <- data.frame(
  year = c(paste("198", 0:9, sep="")),
  crimes = c(sample(100, 10)),
  unsolved = c(sample(40, 10))
)
head(df)
  year crimes unsolved
1 1980     86        2
2 1981     43       23
3 1982     75       37
4 1983      4       33
5 1984     99       20
6 1985     37       28
```

To obtain the proportions of unsolved crimes out of all crimes, define a new variable `$prop.unsolved`by dividing `$unsolved`by `$crimes`:

```
df$prop.unsolved <- df$unsolved/df$crimes
```

Now you can plot these proportions in a barplot:

```
barplot(df$prop.unsolved, main = "Proportions of unsolved crime per year",
    names.arg = df$year, las = 3)
```

[image]

Comment: soo thank you ! your are kinda aswering my question however i have too large of a data set to be input the way you are i think. so i did this but it didnt turn out the same what am i missing?df <- data.frame(
  year = c(paste(dataset$Year, sep="")),
  crimes = c(sample(dataset$Crime.Solved)),
  unsolved = c(sample(dataset$Crime.Solved=="No"))
)
head(df)year crimes unsolved
1 1980      2    FALSE
2 1980      1    FALSE
3 1980      2     TRUE
4 1980      1    FALSE
5 1980      1    FALSE
6 1980      2     TRUE

Comment: The code I sent you obviously works just for the mock data included in my `df`and as such it will undoubtedly also work on your end. As far as *your* data is concerned you need to adapt my code to match your data. Can you maybe upload your data so that I or others can better help you?

Comment: Yes ill upload data ill put it in an image because its to large to see otherwise :) i hope you didnt take my reply the wrong way and im so sorry if it came out wrong. iv just been up working on this project for almost 48 hours straight and this is the last part i need to figure out !!

Comment: Don't worry, everything's fine! Do upload the image if you will. Maybe that'll help.

Comment: thanks for such quick responses you have no idea how grateful i am to hear from someone The link of the image is in the question and the data has 619378 obs and 19 variables

Comment: OK. So, to judge from the image and what your post earlier said, your interest seems to be in the two columns `$Year` and `$Crime.Solved`--correct? What about `$Crime.Type`, does this have to be taken into account as well?

Comment: no crime type dosent need to be considered  just the year and crime solvde

Comment: i just want the proportions of unsolved crime each year... which apparently is done by dividing the unsolved crime value of a given year by the total number of crime that year  and the code should be abel to do that for each year between the years of 1980 -2015